# Mock third party api rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test this third party API using rspec.

So far I am able to able to write the test successfully, but I am calling the real API in this test.

```
require "rails_helper.rb"
require "spec_helper.rb"


class Client
  def initialize
    @host = Rails.application.secrets.key
    @key = Rails.application.secrets.key
  end

def item(id)
   get("item/#{id}")
end

def topstories(start = 0, per_page = 10, expand = true) 
 stories = get('topstories')[start...start + per_page] 
 if expand 
   stories.map! do |story| 
     item(story) 
   end 
 end 
 stories 
end

private

def get(path)
 response = Excon.get(
   'https://' + @host + '/' + path + '.json?print=pretty',
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host' => @host,
      'x-rapidapi-key' => @key,
    }
  )

  return false if response.status != 200

  JSON.parse(response.body) 
  end
end
```

This is the test

```
 describe "topstories" do
   it "returns top stories" do
     client = Client.new
     stories = client.topstories(0, 1)
     expect(stories.length).to eq(1)
     puts stories
   end
 end
```

My question is, how can I test this without calling the real API ?

Comment: You can use a gem such as Webmock or stub the `Excon.get` method.

Comment: i think Excon has the stub method, https://github.com/excon/excon#stubs. and also you can use https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Answer (score 0):

You could use Webmock or VCR, but you don't need to. You can use RSpec instance doubles and mocks. I'll show you that in a sec. First, though, let's make your code a little easier to test:

Accessing `Rails.application.secrets.key` in `Client#initialize` means that you'll need to mock that call chain. I would highly recommend that you inject those values into the class. That'll allow you to send dummy values in when your test runs. Here's what the `initialize` method could look like:

```rb
def initialize(host: nil, key: nil)
  @host = host || Rails.application.secrets.host
  @key = key || Rails.application.secrets.key
end
```

The rest of the application would stay the same, but now you can inject dummy values into the client when the tests run.

With that change in place, you can write the following test:

```rb
describe "topstories" do
  it "returns top stories" do
    
    # setup mock for first call to Excon.get for the top stories
    stories_body = { topstories: [123] }.to_json
    stories_response = instance_double("response", status: 200, body: stories_body)
    allow(Excon)
      .to receive(:get)
      .with(a_string_matching("topstories"), a_kind_of(Hash))
      .and_return(stories_response)

    # setup mock for second call to Excon.get for the actual expanded item
    item_body = { item: 123, title: "title" }.to_json
    item_response = instance_double("item", status: 200, body: item_body) 
    allow(Excon)
      .to receive(:get)
      .with(a_string_matching("item/123"), a_kind_of(Hash))
      .and_return(item_response)

    # create the client with your fake host and key
    client = Client.new(host: "host", key: "key")

    # call the method
    stories = client.topstories(0, 1)

    # expect that the right story was returned
    expect(stories).to match_array([{ "item" => 123, "title" => "title" }])

  end
end
```